# In PySpark, how do I send an RDD to a function to compare a value and return another RDD?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Say we have the next sample data:

```
1,John,Martinez,North Lauderdale,20160101,1
2,John,Martinez,Plantation,20170101,2
3,John,Martinez,North Lauderdale,20161022,1
4,John,Martinez,Pembroke Pines,20181231,0
5,John,Martinez,Plantation,20190101,3
6,John,Martinez,Plantation,20200101,1
7,John,Martinez,Plantation,20210101,9
```

I want to check the last value of each row in the sample file, example 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 9.

```
def func(input):
    if str(input[5]) is "1":
        rdd_trdln = input.map(lambda line: (line, "A"))
    else:
        rdd_trdln = input.map(lambda line: (line, "O"))
        return rdd_trdln
input = sc.textFile("file.txt").map(lambda line: line.split('\t'))
return_FirstFunc = input.map(firstFunc)
```

The error I am getting:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: Here is a word of advice, put some effort in reading at the quick start guide from the official documentation. This question lacks of research and seriously very bad.

Comment: upppssss sorry it was meant for @eliasah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between a Spark `RDD.map()` and a regular Python `map()` function.

When you have `sc.textFile("file.txt").map(lambda line: line.split('\t'))`, you created an RDD of Python lists. Therefore when you call `input.map(func)`, then `func` needs to accept **a list**, not an RDD.

Therefore, `input.map` is your error...

> 'list' object has no attribute 'map'

And that's a Python error, not a Spark error.

If you just want to add a character into the list, then your code would be

```
def func(input):
    if input[5] == "1":
        input.append("A")
    else:
        input.append("O")
    return input
```

Or, more pythonic

```
def func(input):
    input.append("A" if input[5] == "1" else "O")
    return input
```

---

Or you can define your function to take the entire line as a string and split within there.
Having an RDD of lists gets messy to work with and hard to remember sometimes.

```
def convert_func(line):
    """
    This is not returning an RDD. It returns a Python string
    """
    splits = line.split(',') # Your lines are not tab-delimited
    splits.append("A" if splits[5] == "1" else "O")
    return ",".join(splits)

lines = sc.textFile("file.txt")
converted_lines = lines.map(convert_func)
```

You can test like so

```
for line in converted_lines.collect():
    print(line)
```

Comment: but what if I have multiple functions for multiple steps... do I have to do split inside each function?

Comment: It wasn't clear what output you wanted, but currently you have an RDD of (`line`, `"A"` / `"0"`) pairs. If you need to extract data from the line, yes, you need to split again

Comment: is there anyway that i can send the RDD or the data already splitted?

Comment: Sure. `return (splits` instead of `return (line`. Again. If your question was more clear in your expected output, I'll edit my answer

Comment: so basically I want to return the whole RDD line and the new value at the end... for example:

`1,John,Martinez,North Lauderdale,20160101,1,A`

Comment: I am testing this, but so far so good.... thanks a lot @cricket_007 I will let you know if it works.....

Comment: This code worked.... Thanks a lot @cricket_007 .... I already mark this as the solution to my question... I can't vote for it, since my reputation is less than 15... but it is the answer.... thanks a lot again!!!!

Answer (score -1):

From a pure Python side, if you want to map over a standard `list`, you can use the [built-in map function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
input = map(lambda line: line.split('\t'), sc.textFile("file.txt"))
```

Note that Python3 produces different result types (a `map` iterator) to Python 2 (a list).

Comment: `sc.textFile("file.txt")` isn't a Python iterable like a normal list. I don't think this will work that way.